# How can I programmatically save node components?

Tags: nodes, 9

There is a site with number of nodes including layout canvas and site studio components available in a node.

When there will be changes in one of the components (new field added with default value), if I want new component changes to existing page/node, I will need to edit the node, save the component, and save the node. After these steps, I am getting the component change reflected on the node.

Is there any way to programmatically doing that?

With `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('cohesion_layout')->load($uid)`, I get the older JSON component value.

Comment: When you save an updated node, any updated fields on the node are also saved. So to update components, you load the node, update any fields, and save the node. It's not clear what JSON you are referring to here, and you haven't shown us enough code to say what your problem is.

Comment: Hi @Jaypan There is a site studio component. This component is widely used and added to the number of pages. There is modification at the component (some new fields are added with default value). 
If I want to have new changes of component, I have to manually edit the node, edit the component, save the component (without any changes at component as default values are set to new fields) and save the node.
I tried saving the node programmatically, but component related new changes are not coming by only saving the node. Is there any way to get component's new changes to existing pages of site?

Comment: This sounds like something proprietary - Drupal core doesn't come with these components you are mentioning.

Comment: Is the question about Acquia Site Studio?

Comment: @cilefen Yes this is related to Acquia Site Studio.

Comment: This Question needs a bit more information to be answerable with facts.

Comment: Often using the command [`drush entity:save`](https://www.drush.org/12.x/commands/entity_save/)

Answer (score -2):

```php
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('cohesion_layout')->load($node->get('field_layout_canvas')->getValue()[0]['target_id']);
            $layoutCanvas = $entity->getLayoutCanvasInstance();
            foreach ($layoutCanvas->iterateCanvas() as $element) {
                if ($element->getProperty('uid') === 'cpt_cmpt') {
                    $model = $element->getModel();
                    if (!property_exists($model->getValues(), '4df4fbe1-1e4e-4a4d-9032-5f81f270731b')) {
                        $model->setProperty('5ef0h4e0-1e4e-4a4d-9032-5f81f849012b', "the value");
                    }
    $entity->setJsonValue(json_encode($layoutCanvas));
                    $entity->save();
                }
            }
```

Try like this, it worked for me